# How to find words by Ctrl + F on R data sets WIndow or R console?

Tags: r, find, dataset, package, ctrl

I wanted to see all the `data sets` in all the `available packages` in R, for which the command I used was

```
  data(package = .packages(all.available = TRUE))
```

This results in an R window called `R data sets` window like below showing 100s of `data sets` listed `package` wise.

[image]

Now if I want to find something based on words in the above Window, Example say word `cancer` in that window, I am not able to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> on it. How can I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or any other find method in any of the R Windows that pops up. Even in console we can not use searching.

Of course we can copy paste text and search. I want to know if we can do it in R itself.

I can perform <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> only on R Script Window and not any other Window.

**Session Information:**

```
 sessionInfo()
 # R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
 # Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
 # Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Well it works for me on OSX...

Comment: Is it, I am working on Windows 10. Cant perform `Ctrl+F` on any R window or console. Also, my question is restricted to R and not RStudio.

Comment: Are you able to do `Ctrl+F` on RStudio Console?

Comment: And my comment is restricted to R as well.

Comment: I can perform Ctrl+F only on R Script Window and not any other Window.